# How to check/tick radio input in javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="printTemplate" value="5" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="printTemplate" value="2">
```

how can I make value "2" checked (ticked) in javascript?
I have no access to change html code, it is public website.
Here is XPath to this radio with value "2"

```
//*[@id="frmSubmit"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/p[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You would add the `checked` attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="printTemplate" value="2" checked>
```

With jQuery, you can easily target the radio buttons by value too

```
$("input[name=printTemplate][value=2]").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I have no access to html code (public website). Here is also XPath for this radio : //*[@id="frmSubmit"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/p[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input[3]

Comment: How will your javascript be executed then? Is the content in an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

> "I have no access to change html code"

In that case, you could use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByName('printTemplate')[0].checked = true;
```

`[0]` selects the first element with that name, `[1]` the second and so on. If necessary (maybe you want to target multiple elements), you can loop through the the element list.

---

**In reply to question edit:**

> "How can I make value "2" checked (ticked)?"

If there are one or more elements with with the name printTemplate that has `value=2` and you want to target them, you could use:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('printTemplate');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].value == 2) x[i].checked = true;
}
```

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/snsaz/1/)

Comment: document.getElementsByName("printTemplate")[2].checked = true;   << working !! thank you !!

Comment: @maniootek Remember to tick my answer if it helped you :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs for input at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

> **radio**: A radio button. You must use the `value` attribute to define the
>   value submitted by this item. Use the `checked` attribute to indicate
>   whether this item is selected by default. Radio buttons that have the
>   same value for the `name` attribute are in the same "radio button
>   group"; only one radio button in a group can be selected at one time.

So what the doc says, you want to use the attribute `checked`.

```
<input type="radio" name="printTemplate" value="2" checked="checked" />
```

---

Now to do it with JavaScript code, you would set the checked attribute

```
//if you add an id
document.getElementById("foo").checked = true;

//if you only go by name
document.getElementById("frmSubmit").printTemplate[1].checked = true;
```